# cakePHP Session component not initialized?

Tags: session, cakephp, initialization

In AuthComponent.php I have this code:

```
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
App::uses('Router', 'Routing');
App::uses('Security', 'Utility');
App::uses('Debugger', 'Utility');
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
App::uses('BaseAuthorize', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
App::uses('BaseAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class AuthComponent extends Component {
// ...
public $components = array('Session', 'RequestHandler');
// ...
public function login($user = null) {
        $this->_setDefaults();

        if (empty($user)) {
            $user = $this->identify($this->request, $this->response);
        }

        if ($user) {
            $this->Session->renew();    // fails here (Session==null)
            $this->Session->write(self::$sessionKey, $user);
        }
        return $this->loggedIn();
    }
// ...
}
```

When it attempts to execute renew, it fails with a PHP fatal error because $this->Session is null. Is the initialization of this component automatic or am I missing code somewhere?  I should note that this code has been working previously with no known problems. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `debug($this->Session->read());`, if you put that in the first line of the login() method? Do you have the Component Class loaded with `App::uses('Component', 'Controller');`?

Comment: there is no output, i assume because $this->Session == null.

Comment: Usually, I always put all necessary packages in AppController. In your case is `Session`. So, I don't need to do again. In component file, i declared as `App::uses('Component', 'Controller');`. Then, `$this->Session->` can work in my project.

Comment: Please see code edits above to include 'App::uses' lines. A colleague says $this->Session should be initialized by cakePHP, but no one seems to know where or how or why it would fail. No errors are being generated other than the PHP fatal error caused by $this->Session being null.

Answer (score 1):

problem is resolved, sort of. basically, any syntax error anywhere in the code can cause this to happen. even logic errors that are totally unconnected to the code that is failing. (really lovin cake here). so, somewhere in another file in another part of the program entirely, an 's' was dropped off a single variable name, and this caused the Session component inside another cake component to fail to initialize. I don't believe it either, but I've seen it with my own eyes.